# How do I bind to a data source in a user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, controls

when I have controls on a page and I want to data bind them I usually do this in the Page_Load event.

However I have some controls to be databound within a user control. In the code behind for the user control is there a similiar event to Page_Load I could use to databinding?

Answer (score 0):

The [DataBindChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databindchildren.aspx) sounds appropriate for what you are trying to do

```
protected override void DataBindChildren()
{
      // Bind a data source to the server control's child controls.       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a user control using an ascx it has a Page_Load event that can be accessed exactly like a page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx